# Shared dependencies with HELM

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

So, is it possible to share the same pod among helm packages with a common reference. Example:

Scenario:

```
Package A
   ...
   - requirements.yml
         require: C

   
Package B
   ...
   - requirements.yml
         require: C
```

When I run:

```
helm install A
helm install B
```

These two pods for A and B project use the same C pod.
Is it possible? Theres a documentation to help me with that?

PS: The C package in my case is a broker, but both A & B package can be deployed separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2 Helm Charts with shared Redis dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59093888/2-helm-charts-with-shared-redis-dependency)

Comment: @PhoneixS Yes! I like the "umbrella" solution in cases like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work fine with Helm. A little bit of background [here](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#operational-aspects-of-using-dependencies). One key aspect here is `update`:

> - created/updated in that order.

When you update an object, i.e, `kubectl apply` on a Pod/Deployment/Service/etc if the object exists it won't be changed, so you'll end up with the same object in the end.

Also, Kubernetes objects with the same name use the [idempotency principle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#standard-api-terminology):

> All objects will have a unique name to allow idempotent creation and retrieval

In your example:

```
helm install stable/packageA => which also installs PackageC
helm install stable/packageB => will update PackageC, but it's already present and won't change.
```

You have to make sure that the dependencies for `PackageA` for `PackageB` are exactly the same version of `PackageC`.

Comment: When I do it, the error message is: `Error: release myrelease failed: services "C" already exists`

Comment: Different charts? or the same chart?

Comment: I also get `pods "commondependency1-unknown" already exists` errors, considering following scenario: installing chart A, which depends on charts B and C, which both require same version of chart D. I think the answer should be updated. Maybe in the past helm didn't have duplicates check and then it was working fine?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you can ask on a different question, with the details and see if there's something odd with the templates, etc.